# Can Android applications have their variables read/set maliciously?

Tags: java, android

This does not deal with apk piracy what I'm asking about is the code in the apk file.

I know that if you use shared memory and set the mode to public people can change the values that are saved but what about the code in the application? For example if I set a variable to public static int in a game could an outside application change those values?

Another question I have is if I have my application access a remote server could a 3rd party application possibly change the return value that my server would send back?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user can connect with a debugger to any running Android app, and change variables all they want.

Another app - that's another matter, it will probably require a rooted device. Or some clever ADB interaction.

Spoofing server response is relatively easy if you control the network. On the public 3G network - not so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can load classes from other apk's using `createPackageContext` or similar method and then loading the class using the other apps context's classloader. I don't know if you get a copy class from that, that runs only in your part of the VM, or that you can access the actual class itself that is running. Interesting idea to try out. I guess it's the former, and it's secured that way.